# How to get out of runlevel 0 or 6?

Tags: linux, boot, runlevel

Can I use any Linux live distribution to boot into my system and change the file for run level and set it to a valid run level when it has been set to run level 0 or 6?

Answer (score 3):

You should be able to change the run-level, as the default run-level should should either be set in `/etc/inittab` or a sym-link from `/lib/systemd/system/<target name>.target` to `/etc/systemd/system/default.target`. Booting from live means you ignore the installed OS entirely and use the live OS instead, but can still access the hard drive.